# Selector Switch switch, output should be left open or grounded?

Tags: switches, bypass

I am currently designing a circuit and I'm using a Selector Switch. The goal is to control if we are bypassing an other component of the circuit (the 24 VDC will be sent to a PLC that will treat the Bypass). Here is my current design:

[image]

I will not be using the leftmost output, so my question is if I should ground it or leave it open.

Also, this is my first time designing a circuit with a switch.

Thanks a lot,
luisarcher.

## EDIT 1

New design:

[image]

Comment: I don't think so. If the switch is to the left, the whole 24 VDC will go to the ground since the right output is open.

Comment: @luisarcher: yes, but that's a bad thing since electricity takes the path of least resistance, thus nothing else in circuit will get power, and your power supply becomes a literal heater. You can simply use an SPST switch if you have concerns about extra connectors, but leaving it open is fine and won't hurt anything (absent poor physical design)

Comment: Oh ok I see. I changed my design, what if i do i like this. I won't need the ground and since the circuit is open, no current will go there, and thus the other parts of the circuit will be alimented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a DPST (double pole single throw) switch, and want to use it as a SPST switch.

The obvious answer is to simply ignore one of the poles.  This is what your bottom diagram shows.  The circuit shown by the top diagram would also work, but is just asking for trouble if something shorts to the top left contact.

You absolutely don't want to connect that top left contact to ground. *Think* about it.  When the left switch closes, the 24 V supply would be shorted to ground.  Bad.

Of course a even simpler answer is to use a SPST switch in the first place.